# Why am I getting error "This approval request requires the next approver to be determined by the Manager field."?

Tags: approval-process

We have a lead approval process that when submitted for approval, the first step is to seek manager approval. The submitting user has a manager defined in his user record and that manager is active.

However, we are getting the error:

```
Process failed. 
First exception on row 0; first error: MANAGER_NOT_DEFINED, 
This approval request requires the next approver to be determined by the Manager field. 
This value is empty. Please contact your administrator for more information.: []
```

The manager field is not empty; it is filled with an active user.

We tested with a number of users, making sure the manager field is filled in and the manager is active. But I still get the issue.

As I was calling the submit for approval from Apex, I isolated this issue by just submitting the record using the standard Submit for Approval button, but I still get the error.

I isolated the problem even further. In the Winter ’21 version of Salesforce, the approval process submits without error. In the Summary ’20 version of Salesforce the process results in an error. The only difference is the Salesforce versions.

I'm going to open a case with Salesforce, but does anyone else know why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any other approver than Manager of User?

Comment: Can you check if Approver is set to some different user?
(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_troubleshoot.htm&type=5)

Comment: Please see updated question, @Ayu

Comment: lol I'm getting this error when I'm deploying apex class to production but it works fine in my refreshed sandbox. #Mindblown